# jquery recursive loading nested html

Tags: jquery, recursion, get, replacewith

I am creating a HTML page out of mutliple static HTML files using JQuery.  The main html file has place holders for header.html and footer.html, as below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
</head>
<body>
<div class="place-holder" include-file="bbheader.html"></div>
</html>
```

The file bbheader.html contains its own placeholder to load any additional HTML content at runtime.

**Content of bbheader.html**

```
<div class="nav navbar">
    <p> Hello I am bbheader. Thanks for loading me!</p>
    <div class='place-holder' include-file='bbfooter.html'></div>
</div>
```

To load these files, I am using a JQuery script as below:

```
$(function () {
    loadRecursive($(this));
});

function loadRecursive(context) {
    //search matching elements that have 'place-holder' class
    $('.place-holder', context).each(function() {
        $.get($(this).attr('include-file'), function(data, textStatus) {
            $(this).replaceWith(data);
            loadRecursive($(this));
        }, 'html');
});
}
```

Instead of using JQuery.load, I am using get because, load call adds the fetched content as a child of the div context.  What I wanted was to replace the place holder div completely and substitute it with the fetched content. So, I am using get() and replaceWith().

But the function is failing to replace because, it is not getting the correct div context at this line "$(this).replaceWith(data);".  I expected $(this) to be the div which I want to replace, but it seems here 'this' points to some object constructed by JQuery to fetch the content.

I am a novice in JQuery and I am not able to get this right.  Is there a better /altenative way to do this?

thanks..

**Updates:**
Tried as suggested by Leonard and this is the new code:

```
function loadRecursive(context) {
    //search matching elements that have 'place-holder' class
    $('.place-holder', context).each(function() {
        var that = this;
        $.get($(this).attr('include-file'), function(data, textStatus) {
            $(that).replaceWith(data);
            loadRecursive(that);
        }, 'html');
    });
}
```

But it works only for 1st level.  After executing replace?With(), when it goes to recursion, the 2nd call to loadRecursive doesn't get the modified 'self'.

Expected:

```
<div class="nav navbar">
<p> Hello I am bbheader. Thanks for loading me!</p>
<div class='place-holder' include-file='bbfooter.html'></div>
</div>
```

But it still has

```
(<div class="place-holder" include-file="bbheader.html"></div>
```

Am I missing something?

EDIT:

Thanks Leonard!  It works with the following change:

```
function loadRecursive(context) {
    //search matching elements that have 'place-holder' class
    $('.place-holder', context).each(function() {
        var that = $(this);
        $.get(that.attr('include-file'), function(data, textStatus) {
            repl = $(data);
            that.replaceWith(repl);
            loadRecursive(repl);
        }, 'html');
    });
}
```

Comment: Answer posted! Let me know if it worked :)

Comment: Thanks Leonard!  It works with the following change:

function loadRecursive(context) {
 //search matching elements that have 'place-holder' class
 $('.place-holder', context).each(function() {
  var that = $(this);
  $.get(that.attr('include-file'), function(data, textStatus) {
   repl = $(data);
   that.replaceWith(repl);
   loadRecursive(repl);
  }, 'html');
 });
}

Comment: Glad to hear! But actually, I think you should use the one that I wrote last, because I think yours will break if data has multiple nodes at the same first level. Prof: http://jsbin.com/oluqiv/3/edit

Comment: Yes, I am using your code.  ThanQ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple, just save the element:

```
function loadRecursive(context) {
    //search matching elements that have 'place-holder' class
    $('.place-holder', context).each(function() {
        var self = $(this);
        $.get(self.attr('include-file'), function(data, textStatus) {
            self.html(data); // Load the data into the placeholder
            loadRecursive(self); // Fix sub placeholders
            self.replaceWith(self.get(0).childNodes); // Unwrap the content
        }, 'html');
    });
}
```

Don't expect `this` to be the same in different/nestled functions :)

Comment: Changed. But after a call to replaceWith() the 'self' remains old self. $.get is succeeding and getting new data (checked with firebug), but replaceWith doesn't replace?

Comment: is replaceWith() a synchronous method, or do I have to wait for another callback to see the changed contents?

Comment: As an afterthought, 
- Is it safe to use replaceWith() in a recurssive call?  Could it b that its not allowing replacement, since the original div object is still part of function call stack?

Comment: Was in a hurry. Of course, self is still self. We have to do loadRecursive() on the new content, not on self which is the deleted placeholder. Editing..

Comment: How to get hold of the new content..?

Comment: Yeah.. that's the problem. We will have to wrap the data in an element first, and then unwrap it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34328/discussion-between-leonard-pauli-and-mupparthy-ravindranath)

Comment: Aha! Solved it! Look at the last edit!
self.html(data); // Load the data into the placeholder
loadRecursive(self); // Fix sub placeholders
self.replaceWith(self.get(0).childNodes); // Unwrap the content